# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ejb, maven-compiler-plugin

I am a newcomer in Maven and I want to import my application to maven.
I want to, as before, refer on classes in my ejb-project into my war-project. 
I have no errors in classes, but if I make maven install on my Parent project then my war-project give me this error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project SportunionWARModule: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:

[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/AdministratorenView.java:[6,37] package com.sportunion.project.domain does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/AdministratorenView.java:[7,37] package com.sportunion.project.domain does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/AdminEditor.java:[7,37] package com.sportunion.project.domain does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/AdministratorenView.java:[41,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Admins
[ERROR] location: class com.sportunion.AdministratorenView
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/AdministratorenView.java:[42,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Log
[ERROR] location: class com.sportunion.AdministratorenView
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/CSVLoader.java:[8,30] package com.sportunion.project does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/CSVLoader.java:[9,36] package com.sportunion.project.utils does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/CSVLoader.java:[13,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class UsersService
[ERROR] location: class com.sportunion.CSVLoader
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/BenutzerView.java:[9,37] package com.sportunion.project.domain does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/BenutzerView.java:[53,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Users
[ERROR] location: class com.sportunion.BenutzerView
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/Ranking.java:[8,37] package com.sportunion.project.domain does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/Ranking.java:[23,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Users
[ERROR] location: class com.sportunion.Ranking
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/MyUI.java:[8,37] package com.sportunion.project.domain does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/MyUI.java:[9,37] package com.sportunion.project.domain does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/MyUI.java:[10,37] package com.sportunion.project.domain does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/MyUI.java:[35,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Admins
[ERROR] location: class com.sportunion.MyUI
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/MyUI.java:[36,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Users
[ERROR] location: class com.sportunion.MyUI
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/MyUI.java:[37,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Users
[ERROR] location: class com.sportunion.MyUI
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/MyUI.java:[38,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Log
[ERROR] location: class com.sportunion.MyUI
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/LogView.java:[7,37] package com.sportunion.project.domain does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/LogView.java:[30,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Log
[ERROR] location: class com.sportunion.LogView
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/LoginView.java:[8,30] package com.sportunion.project does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/LoginView.java:[9,37] package com.sportunion.project.domain does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/LoginView.java:[10,30] package com.sportunion.project does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/LoginView.java:[11,36] package com.sportunion.project.utils does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/AdministratorenView.java:[101,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Admins
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/AdministratorenView.java:[101,68] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Admins
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/AdministratorenView.java:[101,80] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Admins
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/CSVLoader.java:[13,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable PTServiceLocator
[ERROR] location: class com.sportunion.CSVLoader
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/BenutzerView.java:[118,40] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Users
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/BenutzerView.java:[118,75] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Users
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/BenutzerView.java:[118,86] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Users
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/MyUI.java:[66,64] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Admins
[ERROR] location: class com.sportunion.MyUI
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/MyUI.java:[67,63] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Users
[ERROR] location: class com.sportunion.MyUI
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/MyUI.java:[68,65] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Users
[ERROR] location: class com.sportunion.MyUI
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/MyUI.java:[69,61] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Log
[ERROR] location: class com.sportunion.MyUI
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/LoginView.java:[41,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class AdminsService
[ERROR] location: class com.sportunion.LoginView
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/LoginView.java:[41,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable PTServiceLocator
[ERROR] location: class com.sportunion.LoginView
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/LoginView.java:[42,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LogService
[ERROR] location: class com.sportunion.LoginView
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/LoginView.java:[42,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable PTServiceLocator
[ERROR] location: class com.sportunion.LoginView
[ERROR] /C:/jboss/workspace/Sportunion_Maven/SportunionParent/SportunionWARModule/src/main/java/com/sportunion/LoginView.java:[58,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Admins
```

Does anyone now whats my mistake is?

this is my `pom.xml` of the war-Project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <artifactId>SportunionParent</artifactId>
    <groupId>SportunionParent</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

<groupId>SportunionParent</groupId>
<artifactId>SportunionWARModule</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>SportunionWARModule</name>

<properties>
    <vaadin.version>7.6.4</vaadin.version>
    <vaadin.plugin.version>${vaadin.version}</vaadin.plugin.version>
    <jetty.plugin.version>9.2.3.v20140905</jetty.plugin.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--
      Needed when using the widgetset optimizer (custom ConnectorBundleLoaderFactory).

      For widgetset compilation, vaadin-client-compiler is automatically added on the
      compilation classpath by vaadin-maven-plugin so normally there is no need for an
      explicit dependency.

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>-->        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId> com.vaadin.addon </groupId>
        <artifactId> jpacontainer </artifactId>
        <version> 3.1.1 </version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>           
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <!-- Exclude some unnecessary files generated by the GWT compiler. -->
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/gwt-unitCache/**,
                    WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                <webappDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
                <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                <compileReport>false</compileReport>
                <style>OBF</style>
                <strict>true</strict>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update-theme</goal>
                        <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <!-- Comment out compile-theme goal to use on-the-fly theme compilation -->
                        <!-- <goal>compile-theme</goal> -->
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <!-- Clean up also any pre-compiled themes -->
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/styles.css</include>
                            <include>**/styles.scss.cache</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- The Jetty plugin allows us to easily test the development build by
            running jetty:run on the command line. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- Vaadin pre-release repositories -->
        <id>vaadin-prerelease</id>
        <activation>
        </activation>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

this is my `pom.xml` of my ejb-project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <artifactId>SportunionParent</artifactId>
    <groupId>SportunionParent</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

<groupId>SportunionParent</groupId>
<artifactId>SportunionEJBModule</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>

<name>SportunionEJBModule</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>

                    <!-- without this, the datetime stamp unique id's will be appended to classpath items -->
                    <!-- see: http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html#Snapshot -->
                    <useUniqueVersions>false</useUniqueVersions>
                </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and this one from my ear-project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>SportunionParent</groupId>
    <artifactId>SportunionParent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>SportunionEARModule</artifactId>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>SportunionParent</groupId>
        <artifactId>SportunionWARModule</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>SportunionParent</groupId>
        <artifactId>SportunionEJBModule</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2.Final</version>

                <configuration>
                        <hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>
                        <port>9090</port>
                        <!-- <jbossHome>C:/tools/wildfly-8.0.0.Final</jbossHome> -->
                    </configuration>

    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
  <groupId>SportunionParent</groupId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

I would be happy if anyone could help me... Thanks in advice!

Comment: In which module are you defining your `com.sportunion.project.domain` and `com.sportunion.project.utils` packages? On your EJB module? If so, you have to add it as a dependency to the *pom.xml* file of your WAR.

Comment: yes, in my EJB module... do you have maybe a working example for this dependency?

Comment: I added this : `<dependency>
         <groupId>SportunionParent</groupId>
         <artifactId>SportunionEJBModule</artifactId>
         <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
         <type>ejb</type>
         <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>`  and it still give me the same error ..

Comment: You need to remove the dependency from the EAR and add it to the WAR instead. Please, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, the missing elements are present on your EJB module.

Therefore, you need to **remove** your EJB module as a dependency from your EAR and add it to your WAR module. In your WAR's *pom.xml* file, add the following:

```
<dependencies>
    (...)

    <dependency>
        <groupId>SportunionParent</groupId>
        <artifactId>SportunionEJBModule</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    (...)
</dependencies>
```

Also, since the EJB module is now a dependency of your WAR, I believe there's no need for you to have an EAR. Maven will place your EJB module on the *WEB-INF/lib* of your WAR.

Comment: my problem is that I cannot find my web-inf/lib in my war project ... :-/

Comment: @Dominik, you should have a folder named WEB-INF under *src/main/webapp* of your WAR project. Then, when your WAR is built, Maven packages all your WAR project elements and creates a file, which in your case should be *SportunionWARModule-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war*. If you open that file, you could see that Maven places your dependencies on WEB-INF/lib folder.